# Android: Force phone mic as input even with bluetooth headset

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-audiorecord

I am searching for ways to force Android to use the phone's microphone as the audio input device even if a Bluetooth headset is connected and turned on. Searched the documentation and the Internet and this is the most relevant thing I found about it, but also with no apparent solution to the problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9xdjif/changing_audio_device_routing_within_an_app/

Can't really believe we don't have APIs for this...

Comment: Honestly, it's unbelievable. Especially now that earbuds (which in certain conditions work really really bad as a mic) are getting more and more popular.